# Faster alternative than pandas.read_csv for reding txt files with data

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a project where I need to process large amounts of txt files (about 7000 files), where each file has 2 columns of floats with 12500 rows.

I am using pandas, and takes about 2 min 20 sec which is a bit long. With MATLAB this takes 1 min less. I would like to get closer or faster than MATLAB.

Is there any faster alternative that I can implement with python?

I tried Cython and the speed was the same as with pandas.

Here is the code in am using. It reads the files composed of column 1 (time) and column 2 (amplitude). I calculate the envelope and make a list with the resulting envelopes for all files. I extract the time from the first file using the simple numpy.load_txt(), which is slower than pandas but no impact since it is just one file.

Any ideas?

For coding suggestions please try to use the same format as I use.

Cheers

Data example:

```
   1.7949600e-05  -5.3232106e-03
   1.7950000e-05  -5.6231098e-03
   1.7950400e-05  -5.9230090e-03
   1.7950800e-05  -6.3228746e-03
   1.7951200e-05  -6.2978830e-03
   1.7951600e-05  -6.6727570e-03
   1.7952000e-05  -6.5727906e-03
   1.7952400e-05  -6.9726562e-03
   1.7952800e-05  -7.0726226e-03
   1.7953200e-05  -7.2475638e-03
   1.7953600e-05  -7.1725890e-03
   1.7954000e-05  -6.9476646e-03
   1.7954400e-05  -6.6227738e-03
   1.7954800e-05  -6.4228410e-03
   1.7955200e-05  -5.8480342e-03
   1.7955600e-05  -6.1979166e-03
   1.7956000e-05  -5.7980510e-03
   1.7956400e-05  -5.6231098e-03
   1.7956800e-05  -5.3482022e-03
   1.7957200e-05  -5.1732611e-03
   1.7957600e-05  -4.6484375e-03
```

20 files here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag-tHmG9aFpjcFZPqeTO12FWlMY?e=f6Zk38

```
folder_tarjet="D:\this"

if len(folder_tarjet) > 0:
      print ("You chose %s" % folder_tarjet)


list_of_files =  os.listdir(folder_tarjet) 
list_of_files.sort(key=lambda f: os.path.getmtime(join(folder_tarjet, f)))
num_files=len(list_of_files)

envs_a=[]

for elem in list_of_files:
    
    file_name=os.path.join(folder_tarjet,elem)
    
    amp=pd.read_csv(file_name,header=None,dtype={'amp':np.float64},delim_whitespace=True) 
    
    env_amplitudes = np.abs(hilbert(np.array(pd.DataFrame(amp[1]))))
    envs_a.append(env_amplitudes)

envelopes=np.array(envs_a).T 


file_name=os.path.join(folder_tarjet,list_of_files[1])
Time=np.loadtxt(file_name,usecols=0)
```

Comment: Can you add an excerpt of one of those files? No need for all of those 12500 lines, but maybe 20 first lines?

Comment: I have updated the question by including the data example

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to use csv to store and load big data quantities, if you already have your data in csv you can still convert all of it at once into a faster format. For instance you can use pickle, h5, feather and parquet, they are non human readable but have much better performance in any other metric.

After the conversion, you will be able to load the data in few seconds (if not less than a second) instead of minutes, so in my opinion it is a much better solution than trying to make a marginal 50% optimization.

If the data is being generated, make sure to generate it in a compressed format. If you don't know which format to use, parquet for instance would be one of the fastest for reading and writing and you can also load it from Matlab.

Here you will the [options](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) already supported by pandas.

Comment: There are other options, especially since OP is only using Pandas to read the file, and everything else is just Numpy operations.

Comment: Sure, any other load routine of numpy etc. is also good to go, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @ Ziur, thanks, good point. I could think of doing that in the future. The oscilloscope does have an option store the data as binary instead of ascii

Comment: That sounds much better, use that option, it will be easier and you will save a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: In contrast to optimize pd.read_csv is almost a lost battle, as it is already coded in Cython that is why the speed didn't improved. There is very few little things that you can do in that direction, if you don't implement the read function entirely by yourself, and even if you do so, I don't think will be faster than reading binary data.

Comment: If that oscilloscope's binary format is documented and usable, that is. Just batch-converting the CSV files to e.g. Numpy's `.npy` format is likely to give you quite some gains though :)

Comment: Ok, will look into the binary. But I am still scratching my head why matlab is faster.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in @Ziur Olpa's answer and the comments, a binary format is bound to be faster than to parse text.

The quick way to get those gains is to use Numpy's own NPY format, and have your reader function cache those onto disk; that way, when you re-(re-re-)run your data analysis, it will use the pre-parsed NPY files instead of the "raw" TXT files. Should the TXT files change, you can just remove all NPY files and wait a while longer for parsing to happen (or maybe add logic to look at the modification times of the NPY files c.f. their corresponding TXT files).

Something like this – I hope I got your hilbert/abs/transposition logic the way you wanted to.

```
def read_scans(folder):
    """
    Read scan files from a given folder, yield tuples of filename/matrix.

    This will also create "cached" npy files for each txt file, e.g. a.txt -> a.txt.npy.
    """
    for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "*.txt")), key=os.path.getmtime):
        np_filename = filename + ".npy"
        if os.path.exists(np_filename):
            yield (filename, np.load(np_filename))
        else:
            df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, dtype=np.float64, delim_whitespace=True)
            mat = df.values
            np.save(np_filename, mat)
            yield (filename, mat)


def read_data_opt(folder):
    times = None
    envs = []
    for filename, mat in read_scans(folder):
        if times is None:
            # If we hadn't got the times yet, grab them from this
            # matrix (by slicing the first column).
            times = mat[:, 0]
        env_amplitudes = signal.hilbert(mat[:, 1])
        envs.append(env_amplitudes)
    envs = np.abs(np.array(envs)).T
    return (times, envs)
```

On my machine, the first run (for your 20-file dataset) takes

```
read_data_opt took 0.13302898406982422 seconds
```

and the subsequent runs are 4x faster:

```
read_data_opt took 0.031115055084228516 seconds
```